# fatal: unable to find a suitable socket path

Tags: git

In staging ubuntu server, When get git pull the below error happened.

when below comment I'm ran

sudo chown $(whoami) ~/.git-credential-cache/socket

then below error I'm faced "fatal: unable to find a suitable socket path";  use --socket

Please help us, What I am wrong??

I need the solution to resolve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.